# Why is not every bounded function Riemann integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, riemann-integration, fake-proofs

I know that not every bounded function $f$ on an interval $[a,b]$ is Riemann integrable. However, I seem to have shown that every such function *is* Riemann integrable. I know something must be wrong with my proof, but I can't figure out what it is. Here is what I did.

Let $M$ be a bound of $f$ on $[a,b]$. Thus $|f(x)| \leq M$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. Let $P$ and $Q$ be two arbitrary tagged partitions of $[a,b]$, and let $R(f,P)$ and $R(f,Q)$ be the corresponding Riemann sums, respectively. We have that

$\begin{align*}
|R(f,P) - R(f,Q) | &= \left\vert\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(x_k^*)(x_k-x_{k-1}) - \sum_{k=1}^{n}f(y_k^*)(y_k-y_{k-1}) \right\vert\\
&\leq \sum_{k=1}^{n}|f(x_k^*)|(x_k-x_{k-1}) + \sum_{k=1}^{n}|f(y_k^*)|(y_k-y_{k-1})\\
&\leq \sum_{k=1}^{n}M(x_k-x_{k-1}) + \sum_{k=1}^{n}M(y_k-y_{k-1}).
\end{align*}$

Here, $x_k^*$ and $y_k^*$ are the tags of $P$ and $Q$, respectively. Now, for any $\epsilon > 0$ let $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{2Mn}$. Then if the norms of $P$ and $Q$ are each less than $\delta$,

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}M(x_k-x_{k-1}) + \sum_{k=1}^{n}M(y_k-y_{k-1}) &\leq \sum_{k=1}^{n}M\frac{\epsilon}{2Mn} + \sum_{k=1}^{n}M\frac{\epsilon}{2Mn} \\
&< \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon.
\end{align*}

This implies that the partitions satisfy the Cauchy criterion and thus $f$ is Riemann integrable.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your $\delta$ depends on $n$.

Comment: You cannot assign freely the "norm" of the partition and the number of points it has, since at the very least you have $\lvert b-a\rvert\le n_P\lVert P\rVert$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made the assumption that all tagged partitions have the same number of points $n$. But if you want the norm of your partition to be arbitrarily small, then $n$ will grow larger.

Answer (score 0):

What about an indicator function,  like $\chi_{\Bbb Q}$, which is given by :

$$\chi_{\Bbb Q}(x)=\begin {cases}1\,,x\in\Bbb Q\\0\,,x\notin \Bbb Q\end{cases}$$.

It's bounded. But is it integrable?  Not Riemann integrable.  It's Lebesgue integral is zero however.   This requires some measure theory.